# anchor = link.find('a').get('href') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website using python .I'm getting the o/p but I am getting Following Errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\python-virtual-environments\basspro.py", line 16, in 
anchor = link.find('a').get('href')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/grills')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
#creating soup obj for the products
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product'})
list_links = []
for link in links:
    anchor = link.find('a').get('href')
    print(anchor)
    list_links.append(anchor)
for urls in list_links:
    driver.get(urls)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Are you sure every product has a `<a>` link?

Comment: as i checked none of the div (with class product) elements have `<a>` tag in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Your selecting by `class`, that is also used by an element in another context and these will not provide an `<a>`.

#### How to fix?

Select your elements more specific:

```
links = soup.select('div.productListingWidget li')
```